# HMR not working when updating app/components/{component_name}.html.erb in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

#### Setup:

- `rails new fake_app -d postgresql -c tailwind`

#### Configuration:

- followed all instructions verbatim at [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/ruby-on-rails)

#### Additional gems:

- `bundle add view_component`

#### Created a new component:

- `rails g component header`

#### Updated `tailwind.config.ts` as follows:

```rb
content: [
    './app/components/**/*.{rb,html,erb}',
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
```

#### Edited Procfile.dev as follows:

```
web: bundle exec rdbg --open -n -c -- bundle exec rails s -p 3000
css: bundle exec rails tailwindcss:watch[poll]

# have run this with and without the "[poll]" command
```

#### spinning up server as follows:

`bin/dev`

## Problem:

When I make changes to the component template (in `app/components/#{whatever}.html.erb`) there is no HMR.

## other fixes I've attempted

1. `rails_live_reload` gem
2. `guard-livereload` paired with `rack-livereload` (including required configuration listed on both of their READMEs)
3. `rails assets:clobber` and `rails tailwindcss:clobber` - ineffective
4. solutions in these following SO similar questions:
   [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73197035/rails-7-tailwind-and-view-components-classes-added-to-component-not-compiled)
   [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018297/tailwind-css-responsive-classes-not-working-with-rails-viewcomponent-gem)
5. Solutions attempted from GH: [one](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/119)

## misc.

the views trigger the HMR just fine; But nothing, and I mean nothing, works with these view components.

#### random thing

while following [this github thread](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/160) I came across the comment [here](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/160#issuecomment-1369280171) and attempted to run `rails tailwindcss:build` and go this error:

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
```

But that lead me down a rabbit hole of attempting to correct the `caniuse-lite` issue, which is almost a deeper rabbit hole

## Unambiguous question:

How can I use HMR via tailwind in Rails 7 when editing my tailwind components located in `app/components/`?

Comment: You must reload your page on every change. If you don't want to do it, you can use this awesome gem: https://github.com/kirillplatonov/hotwire-livereload